# Real Analysis: Open sets & continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let f & g be a real valued continuous functions on a metric space M. If A is the set of all x in M such that f(x) < g(x), then show that A is open in M.

Comment: Why do you want us to answer this question? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Through traditional definition of open sets in any metric space, I cannot use the concept of continuity of f & g to prove that set A is open in metric space M

Answer (score 2):

$$A = \bigcup_{c\in\mathbb{R}}\big(\{x \in M \mid f(x) < c\} \cap \{x\in M \mid c < g(x)\}\big).$$

As a union of finite intersections of open sets, this set is open too.

Answer (score 1):

Another one.

(1) The map $\phi : M \to \mathbb R^2$ defined by
$$
x \mapsto \big(f(x),g(x)\big)
$$
is continuous.

(2) The set $E \subset \mathbb R^2$ defined by
$$
E = \big\{(u,v)\in\mathbb R^2 : u < v\big\}
$$
is open.

(3) $A = \phi^{-1}(E)$.

Therefore $A$ is open.

Comment: For that to be sufficient proof, you'll need to add proofs of (1) and (2) as well.